# Offline Rpm installation of docker is failing in RHEL 8.4

Tags: docker, rhel8, docker-ce

While trying to install the docker in offline mode by copying the rpm packages from docker url (https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/8/s390x/stable/Packages) getting the below error

Os version - Red hat linux 8.4 Ootpa

> warning: containerd.io-1.5.11-3.1.e18.s390x.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 621e9f35: NOKEY
> error: Failed dependencies:
> libc.so.6 (GLIBC 2.2) (64bit)
> 13 needed by docker-ce-3:20.10.14-3.e18.3390x
> libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.4) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-3:20.10.14-3.e18.3390x
> libpthread.so. 0 (GLIBC_2.2) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-3:20.10.14-3.18.3390x
> libc.so. 6 (GLIBC 2.2) (64bit) i9 needed by docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.14-3.e18.3390x
> libc.so.6 (GLIBC 2.2.4) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.14-3.e18.5390x
> libdl.so.2 (GLIBC 2.2) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.14-3.e18.3390x
> libpthread.so. 0 (GLIBC 2.2) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.14-3.e18.5390x
> libc.so. 6 (GLIBC 2.2) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-rootless-extras-0:20.10.14-3.e18.5390x
> lib.s0.6 (GLIBC 2.2.4) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-rootless-extras-0:20.10.14-3.e18.s390x
> libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC _2.2) (64bit) is needed by docker-ce-rootless-extras-0:20.10.14-3.e18.3390x`

glibc is available in the env with 2.28 version

`rpm -ga grep glibe glibc-langpack-en-2.28-151. e18.x86 64 glibc-common-2.28-151.e18.x86 64 elibe-devel-2 •28-151.618 x86 64 glibc-headers-2.28-151.18 x86 64 glibc-2.28-151.18 x86 64`

Please guide me on what could be the issue.

Comment: You appear to be trying to install the `s390x` packages on an `x86_64` system?

Comment: In docker downloads it has s390x package for RHEL8 not sure if there are any architecture difference in their package.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for enlightening the difference in package let me try with centos which has x86_64 package of docker.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the RHEL package was with different arch package. After trying with x86_64 it worked.

@Larks Thanks for your quick input & resolution.